# Bouncy Castle scrypt implementation

Tags: java, bouncycastle, scrypt

I'm currently implementing password hashing using *scrypt*. I have already found a nice *scrypt* implementation on GitHub. To my surprise I have also discovered a [*scrypt* implementation in the Bouncy Castle library](http://www.bouncycastle.org/docs/docs1.5on/org/bouncycastle/crypto/generators/SCrypt.html). The class is not documented, Wikipedia didn't mention Bouncy Castle as scrypt implementation provider and I had real trouble finding any code examples of someone using Bouncy Castles scrypt, so this looks somehow suspicious to me.

On the other hand if I had to choose between a GitHubs crypto implementation and Bouncy Castle, I would prefer Bouncy Castle.

So is the Bouncy Castles *scrypt* the 'real thing'? And can I use Bouncy Castles scrypt over the JCA provider API (or do I need to call it directly like here: [AES-256 encryption workflow in scala with bouncy castle: salt and IV usage and transfer/storage](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19301244/aes-256-encryption-workflow-in-scala-with-bouncy-castle-salt-and-iv-usage-and-t))?

---

EDIT: Best answer I could get by now: https://www.bouncycastle.org/devmailarchive/msg13653.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Best answer I could get from the bouncycastle.org mailbox:

> Yes the scrypt implementation is a real thing - that is to say the code is there, and it passes the official test vectors.
>
> A couple of caveats: the implementation doesn’t exploit all parallelism/optimisations that password crackers will, so there’s a bit of defender/attacker asymmetry.
>   Scrypt is also based on the Salsa20 code function, and Salsa20 performs relatively poorly in Java (on par with AES) while performing awesomely (maybe 4-5x quicker) on platforms with SIMD capabilities.
>
> Scrypt isn’t exposed by the BC JCE provider - perhaps I’d say because the JCE only has very primitive expressions of a cost function for PBE (in the form of an interation count).
>   Scrypt has two cost parameters, so it can’t be trivially forced into that API.
>
> If there’s enough demand I guess it could be exposed through JCE with a hard-coded parallelisation parameter or a BC specific parameter spec.

Answer (score 5):

So that people don't have to go to an external site for an answer:

1. Make sure bouncy castle jars are on your build path
2. Import SCrypt like so:

   ```
   import org.bouncycastle.crypto.generators.SCrypt;
   ```
3. Use SCrypt like so:

   ```
   byte[] sCryptHash = SCrypt.generate(plaintext.getBytes(), salt.getBytes(), cpuDifficultyFactor, memoryDifficultyFactor, parallelismDifficultyFactor, outputLength);
   ```

Comment: generate method is static, you can't use it by instantiating a Scrypt object,

Answer (score 2):

You can use the `SCrypt` class with its static method `generate` like this:

```
SCrypt.generate(passwordBytes, salt, costParam, blockSize, parallelization, passwordLength);
```

I can't really say what values you should use for costParam, blockSize or parallelization, the documentation doesn't say much to it. In our studies we used 8 for every of those.

Link to their docus:
BCrypt - https://www.bouncycastle.org/docs/docs1.5on/org/bouncycastle/crypto/generators/BCrypt.html
SCrypt - https://www.bouncycastle.org/docs/docs1.5on/org/bouncycastle/crypto/generators/SCrypt.html

Comment: There are some good information at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11126315/what-are-optimal-scrypt-work-factors , not sure how it would suit current hardware as the answers are bit old.

Comment: Since the BC implementation uses Java, how does it compare to the native code (C++) implementations (see https://github.com/wg/scrypt and its forks)? Note that for Scrypt (or any key stretching) to be effective against attackers, it needs to run as fast as possible.