# Speeding up scrypt on android

Tags: android, scrypt

I am using [scrypt](https://github.com/wg/scrypt) in making an Android app and it takes a very long time to compute the hash. This is how I call it:

```
String hash = Base64.encodeToString(SCrypt.scrypt("password".getBytes(), "salt".toString().getBytes(), 16384, 16, 2, 128), Base64.DEFAULT);
```

And this is how I declared the dependency in Gradle:

```
compile group: 'com.lambdaworks', name: 'scrypt', version: '1.4.0'
```

It takes almost a minute to compute the hash on my Nexus 6P and that is of course, very slow. Does anyone have any idea on how this can be made much faster? I am new to this and hence, clueless on why it is so slow and how to speed it up.

Comment: How can you tell with everything crammed into one line, that makes debugging and understanding a lot harder. Please provide a [mcve], all the other cruft does not apply to `script()`. You should be aiming for about 100ms.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the `SCrypt.scrypt()`parameters should be optimized for your use cases.

Some numbers in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11126315/what-are-optimal-scrypt-work-factors) and [this slide p17](http://www.tarsnap.com/scrypt/scrypt-slides.pdf)

> (N = 2^14, r = 8, p = 1) for < 100ms (interactive use)
>
> (N = 2^20, r = 8, p = 1) for < 5s (sensitive storage)

and the `N`,`r`,`p` meanings:

> N: General work factor, iteration count.
>
> r: blocksize in use for underlying hash; fine-tunes the relative memory-cost.
>
> p: parallelization factor; fine-tunes the relative cpu-cost

So if you want less time, the `N` should be reduced. `r` and `p` is related to hardware, it need more runtime environment to adjust dynamically.

Comment: The time to perform a script operation is controlled by the value of `N` and the hardware it is run on. For slower hardware decrease the value of `N` to an acceptable time, ~100ms is a reasonable time vs security tradeoff.

Comment: So, is my phone just slow when it is taking a minute to compute? I don't mind a few seconds tbh.

Comment: I don't think it will make your phone feel "slow" when computing this UNLESS you put it in ui-thread. You could refer to async task in android to improve user experience.

Comment: I am sorry I am unable to understand. After I tap on the button to the compute, it take about 60-70 seconds to compute, which is evidently way too much time. How to speed it up?

Comment: Have you decreased the number `16384` in `SCrypt.scrypt(...)` ? try 8000, 4000, 2000 instead and watch the speed and result

Comment: Even using async task doesn't help speed it up though. I have seen other apps which use these parameters but are faster. What's the issue?

Comment: I have this issue too. N is 2^14 but it takes long time (~60s) in some phones (Actually on all phones except mine :)) )

Comment: @AlirezaOmidi what are the whole params and scrypt text length? like r? [RFC7914](https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc7914) example is no such a big N value. (The max N is 1048576)

Comment: @sakiM I resolved the issue by just creating an `.apk` file and installing it. Using Run or Debug in Android Studio was the problem. I think there is a huge overhead in profiling the running app which Android Studio was doing. the parameters are OK (`N=16384`).